# Plone: Passing connection string to zmysqlda from external file

Tags: mysql, plone, zope

I am connecting to database in Mysql from Plone(Zope) using ZMySQLDA connector in which it requires connection string in database username passwd format.
But i need the connection string to be passed from external file so that i can change it from external file without changing the connection object from zope management interface.
Is it possible ?
Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: How often does this need to change and how does the change need to be triggered? When Plone starts? With every connection?

Comment: Whenever zmysqlda tries to connect to database it should fetch connection string from the external file.

Comment: That's going to be a bit messy because those database adapters maintain pooled connections, and you're going to have to make sure your solution is thread-safe. This is not an answer, but if I was trying to to this, I'd write a custom view that served as a proxy for the database connection, then start investigating the DA interface to figure out how to safely close and open connections. Updating the connection string will be the easy part.
I think you may find that by the time you've done all that, you could have switched to using SQLAlchemy and be much happier.

Answer (score 1):

Not easily.

You don't say how exactly you need to get the connection string to be stored on the filesystem: if the only restriction is that it needs to *be* on the filesystem, then that's what z3c.saconfig is for. It gets the configuration from zcml, like:

```
<configure xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/db">
  <include package="z3c.saconfig" file="meta.zcml"/>
  <engine name="otn"  url="postgresql://otnplone@${buildout:dbhost}/otnunit" />
  <session name="pas.plugins.sqlalchemy" engine="otn" />  
</configure>
```

But z3c.saconfig is for SQLAlchemy, and you'd need to switch from ZMySQLDA to SQLAlchemyDA, and even then it wouldn't be automatic.  If you're prepared to make that switch, I can probably help you with the rest.

As far as I can see ZMySQLDA is an obsolete adapter (really, I don't see many people using the Zope DAs at all, but at least SQLAlchemyDA works with SQLAlchemy, which is very well maintained).

IF you use z3c.saconfig, then you could maintain the connection strings with collective.saconnect (no longer in a file, but it's in the Plone control panel rather than the ZMI), and then you are able to have an adapter rebuild connections when the connection string changes.  Just using z3c.saconfig alone won't let you do that.

I see no easy way to make changing a file-system object update a connection string.  At the very least you would need to traverse to some view after modifying the file to effect the change.

Comment: You got me right! I just need the connection string to be in the external file that is the only restriction. But I want to stick with ZMySQLDA only. is there any configuration present for ZMySQLDA ? or can we create any config file for it ? please help me to move ahead Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not likely going to ever happen.  See my edited comments above.